# Perl compare two files and copy lines to new file

Tags: perl

I’m a beginner in perl and I’m trying to compare two files with perl. One contains a list of id’s the other one has strings which contain id’s and more text. I want to copy the lines with matching id’s to a third file, but instead of the correct strings I only get a number. What have I done wrong?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( IDS , "<id.txt");
my @ids = <IDS>;
chomp(@ids);
close IDS;
my $id = @ids;
open ( META , "<meta.txt");
my @metas = <META>;
chomp(@metas);
my $meta = @metas;

open ( OUT1, ">>", "outtest.txt");
foreach $id (@metas){
    print OUT1 "$meta"."\n";
}
close OUT1;
close META;
```

Comment: where do you match IDs? your question says you want those 'with matching IDs' in another file, where is there any matching going on? Also, `my $scalar = @array;` will count elements of @scalar and store result in $scalar. Not sure that is what you want, but it does not seem to be used anyway later, just saying...

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl

Comment: Thank you, @bytepusher and mpapec, your comments are enlightening for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try With hash variables to get the output:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( META , "<meta.txt");
my %idsValues = (); #Create one new HASH Variable
while(<META>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if($line=~m{<id>(\d+)</id>\s*<string>([^<>]*)</string>})
    {
        $idsValues{$1} = $2; #Store the values and text into the HASH Variable
    }
}
close(META); #Close the opened file
my @Values;
open ( IDS , "<id.txt");
while(<IDS>)
{
    my $line = $_;
    if($line=~m/<id>(\d+)<\/id>/i)
    {
    #Check if the value presents in the file and push them into ARRAY Variable.
        push(@Values, "IDS: $1\tVALUES: $idsValues{$1}") if(defined $idsValues{$1} );
    }
}
close(IDS); #Close the opened file
open ( OUT1, ">>", "outtest.txt");
print OUT1 join "\n", @Values; #Join with newline and Print the output line in the output file.
close OUT1; #Close the opened file
```

Comment: id.txt
<id>1</id>
<id>2</id>
<id>3</id>
<id>4</id>
<id>5</id>
<id>6</id>

meta.txt
<id>1</id><string>This is the sequence number is 1.</string>
<id>2</id><string>This is the sequence number is 2.</string>
<id>3</id><string>This is the sequence number is 3.</string>
<id>4</id><string>This is the sequence number is 4.</string>
<id>6</id><string>This is the sequence number is 4.</string>